# How to delete lines in an Excel file using the pandas library

Tags: python, excel, pandas, function, openpyxl

Here is my code

```
def delete_teach():
    df = pd.read_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')
    print("Enter the name of the teacher you want to remove:")
    print(df['Teachers'])
    delete_teach_vyb=input("Enter: ")
    print("You are about to delete ", delete_teach_vyb)
    return df.query("Teachers != @delete_teach_vyb")
    df.save()
```

data is not deleted when I enter the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the `df` back to `excel` file. Use [`df.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
def delete_teach():
    df = pd.read_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')
    print("Enter the name of the teacher you want to remove:")
    print(df['Teachers'])
    delete_teach_vyb=input("Enter: ")
    print("You are about to delete ", delete_teach_vyb)
    df = df.query("Teachers != @delete_teach_vyb")
    df.to_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')
```

**Also, `df.save` is deprecated. `df.to_pickle` is the correct method.**

Comment: xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'bd1.xlsx'

Comment: Please specify a path on which you have permissions to write. And pass that path like: `df.to_excel('/my/path/bd1.xlsx')`

Comment: all pages have been deleted

Comment: Sorry, added `sheet_name` param in my answer. Please check.

Comment: thank you, you saved my term paper, would kiss you !!!

Comment: No, I think a thankyou is just fine. Good luck with your paper!

Comment: can I have one more question please?
can you help with adding?

Comment: Please don't add it in this post. Post a new question altogether.

Comment: I can't. I can add a question after 90 minutes

Comment: Then please wait for 90 minutes and then add.

Comment: I loaded the task